# address verification with USA credit card

Tags: php

I want to check whether user entered address is correct with his credit card details, but I don't want to charge any user to verify credit card address.
I have tried to verify address using stripe: **http://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token** but when I retrieve token address fields returns `null`.

```
Stripe\Token JSON: {
"id": "tok_15xBRLBohZKQWMNn8j62VIZn",
"livemode": false,
"created": 1430376391,
"used": false,
"object": "token",
"type": "card",
"card": {
    "id": "card_15xBRLBohZKQWMNnFNlqKusp",
    "object": "card",
    "last4": "4242",
    "brand": "Visa",
    "funding": "credit",
    "exp_month": 8,
    "exp_year": 2016,
    "country": "US",
    "name": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_city": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "cvc_check": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "metadata": {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some example PHP code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))?  Also, use 4 spaces before each line of the JSON block to pre-format it like code.  Also, include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [Hpw do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: I will need your real merchant account number and auth key.

Comment: @will I already created stripe account which now is in test mode. I collect users address and credit card details from that i create token using :            `    \Stripe\Token::create(array(
      "card" => array(
        "number" => "4242424242424242",
        "exp_month" => 5,
        "exp_year" => 2016,
        "cvc" => "314"
      )
    ));` then i retrive this token as shown in [link](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token) i also tried to use live credit card details but address field sows null values.

Comment: @misunderstood Test secret key: sk_test_YtxqjFHm1JLQcQ3ve1TQQHOt  and publisheble key: pk_test_jHvpMBP2cV8SbszbJImErxbP

Answer (score 1):

You never entered an address when you created the `card` object, so there is no address to be verified.

After you create the `card` object, update it to add the user's address, and then the `address_line1_check` should pass or fail.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_BLAHBLAH");

$cu = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve("cus_BLAHBLAH");
$card = $cu->sources->retrieve("card_BLAHBLAH");
$card->address_line1 = "123 Bumbleberry Road";
$card->address_city = "Ridgewood";
$card->address_state = "NJ";
$card->address_zip = "07450";
$card->address_country = "US";
$card->save();
```

> https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_card

Comment: i want to check whether users manully entered address and the address register with the credit card is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

I like to start with an array, and use json_encode.  But that's me.

It turns out that is the RESPONSE you get to your request.

You have to use these parameter in curl:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens \
   -u sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2: \
   -d card[number]=4242424242424242 \
   -d card[exp_month]=12 \
   -d card[exp_year]=2016 \
   -d card[cvc]=123
```

### Example RESPONSE

[image: example response]

```
$json = json_encode(array("id" => "tok_15xBRLBohZKQWMNn8j62VIZn",
"livemode" => false,
"created" => 1430376391,
"used" => false,
"object" => "token",
"type" => "card",
"card" => array(
    "id" => "card_15xBRLBohZKQWMNnFNlqKusp",
    "object" => "card",
    "last4" => "4242",
    "brand" => "Visa",
    "funding" => "credit",
    "exp_month" => 8,
    "exp_year" => 2016,
    "country" => "US",
    "name" => null,
    "address_line1" => null,
    "address_line2" => null,
    "address_city" => null,
    "address_state" => null,
    "address_zip" => null,
    "address_country" => null,
    "cvc_check" => null,
    "address_line1_check" => null,
    "address_zip_check" => null,
    "dynamic_last4" => null,
    "metadata" => '')
  ));

Stripe\Token JSON: {$json}
```

Comment: from above json response the address fields shows null values. Is it because my account is in test mode? whether i should user live secret and publishable key?

Comment: I was kidding on the number and auth codes. But that is an example Response.  You send only the card#, expiration., and cvc.  And they respond with a token and null address.  You are using wrong Request.

Comment: I want to check whether users manully entered address and the address register with the credit card is correct or not

Comment: Generally you cannot verify an address on a merchant account.  What they do is charge you a higher rate when there is a type on the address. They like charging higher rates and do not want to help you save when they can make more money.  It's about them making money, not you.

Comment: thanks for reply. Is their any another option for this?